# `INFO memory` doesn't work in Redis

Tags: redis

I tried `INFO memory` in `redis-cli`

but empty result came back.

Am I missing any configuration for this?

Redis version is `2.8.17`.

Comment: can you output all the commands that you've wrote beginning with the `redis-cli`  until you got an empty result?

Comment: @bitoiu `./redis-cli -p 1234 INFO memory`

Comment: you have absolutely no output? is it a protected instance (password)?

Comment: @bitoiu Yes, completely empty. It doesn't use any security-related configuration.

Comment: not sure how's that possible to be honest. can you instead run the client, and run `info memory` within the client itself?

Comment: what happens when you run, `redis-cli -p 1234 info`? do you still get no output?

Comment: Really sorry for confusion. I did the command to the Sentinel instance. It works fine with the Redis instance. Thank you for responses.

Answer (score 0):

I did the command to the Sentinel instance.

It works fine with the Redis instance.